How to preview image after selecting image in active admin(using active storage for image)
I have a model Products.
class Product < ApplicationRecord
 has_many_attached :images
end

the form
  form do |f|
    f.inputs 'General' do
      f.input :name
      f.inputs 'Product Image & Video' do
        f.input :images, as: :file, input_html: { multiple: true }, hint: f.object.images.attached? ? f.object.images.map { |image| image_tag(image, style: 'max-width: 300px;') }.join.html_safe : ''
        f.input :video_url, as: :string
      end
    end


        f.input :video_url, as: :string
      end
    end
    f.actions
  end

I am unable to update the product with this approach. The image also doesnt change when new image is uploaded.
I want to display the image that has been selected to upload. As for the edit form, I want to display the images that has already been uploaded and replace them if new images are selected to upload.
As you can see, I have used the hint attribute, but it is causing error when updating the product.
Additional:
how can I delete each image?
